# center text and image in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am coming to you with a seemingly simple question. Yet I was not able to find a suitable solution.
I have an Image- and a TextView inside a RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/page2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="@drawable/separator_vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="DemoText"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/delete_text"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="DemoText"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_text"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Currently only the TextView is centered in their respective RelativeLayout.
How can I align the ImageView and the TextView together in the center of the RelativeLayout?

Comment: try to the relative layout with weights and width 0 dp use `android:gravity="center"` hopefully it will solve your issue.. :)

Comment: Thank this solved it! :)

Comment: Sure, I can close the question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set

`android:gravity="center"`

to the **parent relativeLayouts having weights**.

So that it centers its children, as you wanted !!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the two views in another layout and center it. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/delete_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DemoText"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout has different characteristic, what you need is ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout inside. Of course you can wrap RelativeLayout with something else but it is unnecessary nesting:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/page2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/delete_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/delete_text"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delete_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DemoText"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/edit_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_text"
        android:src="@drawable/edit_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DemoText"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```